# Construction apply from : to: in Gradle script

Tags: groovy, gradle, task, apply

I met this construction **apply from: - to:** in one Gradle build and I do not understand what it does

```
task ("someName", type: someType) { task ->
        def path = "src/main/tran/${transformType}.groovy"

        def global = "$rootDir/$path"
        apply from: global, to: task
}
```

If this something Groovysh or it is entirely Gradle concept?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`apply` is a Gradle concept. `apply from:` applies the given script to the current project. In other words, simple names occurring in the script (e.g. `path`) will be resolved using the `project` object. To give an example, applying a script containing `println path` will print `project.path`.

`apply from:, to:` applies the given script to the object specified by `to:`. To give an example, applying a script containing `println path` to `task` will print `task.path`.

Comment: any idea if this is possible
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70331008/sending-an-input-to-the-gradle-file-extension-when-using-apply-from