# sending an input to the gradle file extension when using "apply from:"

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

in gradle, you can segregate your main gradle file, for example, in android if you have a big `build.gradle` file you can divide this big file to small parts and then include them in the target `build.gradle` file

```
apply from: "$jacocoDir/jacoco_module.gradle"
```

now my question is can we send an argument from the `build.gradle` file to the `jacoco_module.gradle`

for the above example imagine I have a `jacoco_module.gradle` and `build.gradle` that applies the jacoco_module how can I define the jacoco git ignore in the `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to get information into the second script.  If you have something like this in `build.gradle`:

```
ext {
    someMagicNumber = 42
}
apply from: 'jacoco_module.gradle'
```

You could have something like this in `jacoco_module.gradle`:

```
tasks.register('magic') {
    doLast {
        println "Magic Number Is ${someMagicNumber}"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Jeff for the answer any other way that we can explicitly pass the information to the second script

Comment: "any other way that we can explicitly pass the information to the second script" - Yes.  There are a lot of things you could do.  You could use property files.  You could use System properties.  You could set OS environment variables.  You could add state to the Gradle project.  Are you simply asking if there are ways?

Comment: I mean the way that you suggested here in java concept is like defining a static variable somewhere and access to it from multiple places, but I'm looking for something like sending an argument in a function or class constructor, not sure if it's possible though

Comment: "but I'm looking for something like sending an argument in a function or class constructor, not sure if it's possible though" - Including an external build file isn't really the same kind of thing as calling a function or a constructor.  It is more like a `#include` than an invocation.